# What would cause RPM's to drop when pressing the gas pedal?

Tags: ford, focus, rpm

Bunch of issues on a 2018 Ford Focus SE, less than 50,000 miles still. Took it to the dealership then the oil low pressure light came on. Apparently, they replaced the oil pump, crankshaft, timing belt, and a few gaskets and bolts. Never gave any codes just the low-pressure light.

It's stalled multiple times when backing out RPMs would drop like in the video but then just die instead of coming back up. It's also dropped to 25MPH from 60MPH going uphill once, RPMs didn't come up even with the pedal to the floor. It sounds like it's gonna fall apart especially from a cold start and rattles when at a stop sign/light.

[Short video showing it dropping](https://streamable.com/m5xc9t)

Any help would be appreciated, taking it back to the shop soon and don't want them to be all "it's good" to me again when it's obvious something is wrong, still under power train and extended warranties so feeling like they're just not trying since I don't have to pay for it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The thing about the dealership is, they aren't paying for it either. The manufacturer is paying for it. Take it back to them and show them what's wrong with it as you see it. If they are lax in trying to get it fixed, call up the District Ford Rep (you can find them without too much trouble) and get them involved. You'll get action then.

Comment: Thank you, will call the district rep. Called the dealership back today and they just gave me the run around.

Comment: Is this happening all the time or intermittently?

Comment: Every time from a cold start, then intermittently while engine is warm and stopped at stop sign/light. Doesn't appear to happen in park, but I don't typically idle the engine for long.